# Every probability space can be embedded into a full probability space

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am reading Teller and Fine's article [*A Characterization of Conditional Probability*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2690065.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ad9b11baf9ed497fbbd7e799d54fe3420) and I am having trouble checking one of the claims.

A probability space $(X, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is **full** if for every $A\in\mathcal{F}$, $P$ is a surjection from $\{B\in\mathcal{F}:B\subset A\}$ onto $[0, P(A)]$. The claim is that every probability space can be embedded into a full probability space (an **embedding** of $(X, \mathcal{F}, P)$ into $(X',\mathcal{F}', P')$ in this context is an injective homomorphism $f: \mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}'$ such that $P'f=P$). The intuitive construction is to embed $(X, \mathcal{F}, P)$ into $(X\times[0,1], \mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}, P\otimes\mu)$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel algebra and $\mu$ the uniform probability distribution (the embedding map is $A\mapsto A\times[0,1]$). However, I am having a hard time seeing why $(X\times[0,1], \mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}, P\otimes\mu)$ is full. Clearly all the measurable rectangles satisfy the desired condition. My current strategy is to check that the collection $\{S\in\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}: P:\{T\in\mathcal{F}: T\subset S\}\rightarrow[0, P(S)]\text{ is a surjection}\}$ is a $\sigma$-field. But I got stuck here...any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps consider the function $F(x)= P(S \cap X \times [0,x])$. $F$ is increasing, $F(1)=P(S)$, and $F$ is continuous. Apply the intermediate value theorem. Sets of the form  $S \cap X \times [0,x]$ are measurable.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 Thanks! This is ingenious!